# Optional Parameters on a search query degrades a lot its performance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query with a dozen of optional parameters that I call like:

```
select *
from table
where (@param1 is null or field1 = @param1) and
      (@param2 is null or field2 = @param2) and
      (@param3 is null or field3 = @param3) and
      (@param4 is null or field4 = @param4) and
      (@param5 is null or field5 = @param5)
```

It works perfectly fine, but its performance is awful. It takes minutes to complete while the same query runs in seconds using just the parameters needed each time.

Example, this runs in seconds on the same data:

```
select *
from table
where field2 = @param2 and
      field4 = @param4 and
      field5 = @param5
```

Is there any possibility to optimize the first query so it would use the indexes corresponding to the parameters passed? Now I'm forced to dynamically build the SQL sentence from my application so it only contains the parameters needed (second example), it takes more time to code and it's easier to introduce errors that you would only detect at runtime when you use a concrete parameter.

Thank you.

Comment: Did u try the parameter sniffing ?

Comment: Did you try adding a recompile hint?

Comment: Erland Sommarskog wrote an excellent article - [Dynamic search conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: Thanks for all the advises, and thank you very much for that fantastic article, it addresses all the doubts I was having. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the article linked by @Damien_The_Unbeliever I will add the Query Hint OPTION (RECOMPILE), so it will be compiled every time I call it, and it will be optimized using the indexes corresponding to the parameter values passed.

```
select *
from table
where (@param1 is null or field1 = @param1) and
      (@param2 is null or field2 = @param2) and
      (@param3 is null or field3 = @param3) and
      (@param4 is null or field4 = @param4) and
      (@param5 is null or field5 = @param5) 
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

But as @Erwin_Smout has said and the article also states, on more complex queries it will be better to build the sentence dynamically.

Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 1):

"Is there any possibility to optimize the first query so it would use the indexes corresponding to the parameters passed ?"

No.

You are making the common mistake of attempting to unify multiple distinct query types into one, for the mistaken purpose/goal of trying to avoid to write lots of SQL.

One single query means there will be only one single access path to the data, and that single access path will be used for each and every instance of the query (e.g. regardless of whether, say, param1 is really used or not).

Queries should be written in such a way that they still *allow* the DBMS to determine the access path to the data.  This determination is done when the query is compiled, not when it is executed.  (This distinction gets somewhat blurred by facilities such as dynamic SQL, but that doesn't mean it has entirely gone away.)  That means that the query optimizer cannot possibly take into account what the parameter values are, for a particular invocation of the query, when determining the access path.

Your way of writing the query actively deprives the DBMS of the possibility to determine good access paths.  And you get rewarded with the performance you deserve for doing this.

The solutions are as you already observed : generate the SQL dynamically depending on which selection criteria actually are to be used (and take care of all possible injection issues), or (even better, performance-wise) provide a limited set of predefined query possibilities.

Comment: The answer isn't actually No. Adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` would have the desired effect since [SQL Server 2008 SP1 CU5](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html#SPandCUs). At the cost of recompiling the query each invocation. Another good article on the topic is [Parameter Sniffing, Embedding, and the RECOMPILE Options](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options)

Comment: Your remark is better elaborated in full as an answer in its own right, so you'll have the opportunity to also specify ***where*** to add this option.  As well as elaborating in detail on the associated costs.

Answer (score 1):

If indexed correctly, this will allow an Index Seek rather than a Scan because it includes a filter for each column:

```
select *
from testtable
where (field1 = @param1) and
      (isnull(field2, '_Dummy') = iif(@param2 is null, isnull(field2, '_Dummy'), @param2)) and
      (isnull(field3, '_Dummy') = iif(@param3 is null, isnull(field3, '_Dummy'), @param3)) and
      (isnull(field4, '_Dummy') = iif(@param4 is null, isnull(field4, '_Dummy'), @param4)) and
      (isnull(field5, '_Dummy') = iif(@param5 is null, isnull(field5, '_Dummy'), @param5))
```

Earlier code provided did not allow for null column values:

```
select *
from table
where (field1 = @param1) and
      (field2 = iif(@param2 is null, field2, @param2)) and
      (field3 = iif(@param3 is null, field3, @param3)) and
      (field4 = iif(@param4 is null, field4, @param4)) and
      (field5 = iif(@param5 is null, field5, @param5))
```

Comment: Sadly I can't use it, many rows have null values. I think I will use the OPTION (RECOMPILE) when the query is simple, and build dynamically a new SQL each time when the query is more complex.

Comment: @MarcGuillot I have edited it to provide a work-around for the Nulls.

Comment: Yes, it will work, but won't it have the same problem of performance than my original query ?. Now your filter are expressions, so it won't use any index.

Answer (score 1):

I would usually write your query this way. It compares each column to its variable unless the variable is null, in which case it compares the column to itself. You can add the recompile hint, but I rarely need it.

```
select *
from table
where (field1 = isnull(@param1, field1) and
      (field2 = isnull(@param2, field2) and
      (field3 = isnull(@param3, field3) and
      (field4 = isnull(@param4, field4) and
      (field5 = isnull(@param5, field5)
option (recompile)
```

Edit:
When the columns can contain null, you can write the query using isnull/coalesce to convert null to a value, such as blank or zero depending on your datatype.

```
select *
from table
where (isnull(field1, '') = coalesce(@param1, field1, '') and
      (isnull(field2, '') = coalesce(@param2, field2, '') and
      (isnull(field3, '') = coalesce(@param3, field3, '') and
      (isnull(field4, '') = coalesce(@param4, field4, '') and
      (isnull(field5, '') = coalesce(@param5, field5, '')
option (recompile)
```

Comment: It won't work when one of the fields contains a null value, because null = null is False. Check this query : select case when null = null then 'equal' else 'different' end as compare_nulls

Comment: Yes, that is true. Your query didn't account for null column values, so I didn't either.